# What's the significant difference between these two image processing libs of c/c++?

Tags: c, image-processing

1. [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)
2. [GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html)

Is there some experienced user can share it?

I need to know the difference to decide which to choose.

Comment: Is this still the thresholding question?  Why are you using C/C++, and not something like Matlab?  If you're going to stay with C/C++, then you might also want to add the Insight Toolkit (www.itk.org)

Comment: I'm 100% unfamiliar with MatLab.So I want to choose a library in c/c++

Comment: What types of problems are you looking to solve here?  For a lot of simple drawing I really like ImageMagick, but I'm not sure that would suit your needs or not because I have no idea what you plan on doing.

Comment: I'm trying to solve OCR problem,which involved many complicated things like FFT ..

Comment: Then you really want to become familiar with matlab.  In matlab, calling the fft on an image is 'fft2(image)'.  In C/C++, you need to get an fft library (like fftw.org's), compile it, configure it, make sure you know how to use it, figure out threading problems (because the fft is automatically parallelizable), etc etc etc.  Matlab will be way, way simpler for you, and already has binarizing functions built in.

Comment: Seems you managed to persuade me,but how can I get started with matlab which I've no experience with at all?

Comment: MATLAB is very expensive - try Octave, which is a free MATLAB-compatible alternative

Comment: If you want to familiarize yourself with Matlab, read the help. It is seriously useful. Start here: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/bqr_2pl.html

Answer (score 1):

A vote for OpenCV, if running Intel processor, it can use the Intel IPP optimized libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between those libs is huge.
The **OpenCV** library have a lot of image processing functions for solving various tasks that are common in computer vision. 
The **GIL** library haven't such algorithms at all. It provides easy and strongly typed interfaces to work with different image formats (BGR, CMYK, etc) and that's all. Of course, you can write your own image processing algorithms that works with GIL types. But if want to work with feature descriptors, keypoints, image segmentation and so on - the GIL is not a good choice. IMHO.